# What is pd in opencart model files?

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to get a better grasp of Opencart's model files but pd. and p. and c. baffles me. Can someone explain what are they and how to interpret them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the **synonyms** (we could also a little offensively say *shortcuts*) to table names. Like if You want to get certain `product` and `product_description` columns, You would do:

```sql
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    product.price,
    product.tax_class_id,
    product.image,
    product_description.title,
    product_description.description
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id
WHERE product.product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
ORDER BY product_description.title
```

But if You use synonyms, You could type a little less:

```sql
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.price,
    p.tax_class_id,
    p.image,
    pd.title,
    pd.description
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
WHERE p.product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
ORDER BY pd.title
```

Is it clear now? This is not about OpenCart but about pure `SQL`.

Comment: Yes. As always, I had it figured out after I asked the question but thanks anyways. Great if you could point to resources in understanding Opencart model files.

Comment: I doubt there are any resources directly for OpenCart, but googling for `MVC` architecture should point You the right way. The `Model` classes are just wrappers for functions which are wrappers for SQL queries and CRUD operations ( **C** reate, **R** ead, **U** pdate, **D** elete). You then call `$model->function()` to execute certain query, the function names are enough self-describing to understand them.

Comment: In addition, at OpenCart, sometimes the model classes are misused e.g. for email sending (like the `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php` and method `confirm()`) or other operations (or data manipulation) which should take place in controller classes, just for the record.

Comment: While this is correct, the query's length isn't the only reason why synonyms are used. In OpenCart you can have a database prefix `DB_PREFIX`, so you would have to put the full table name including the prefixes all throughout every query however the only one required using this method is the one to set the synonym

Comment: @dkjain Please accept the answer so it is clear the question has an solution ;-) Thanks!